# What's the correct way to not update an out variable

Tags: c#

I've implemented a `TryParse` function for a class `MinMax` like this:

```
    public static bool TryParse(string s, out MinMax result)
    {
        var parts = s.Split(' ');
        if (parts.Length != 2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        float min;
        float max;
        if (!float.TryParse(parts[0].Trim(), out min) || !float.TryParse(parts[1].Trim(), out max))
        {
            return false;
        }
        result = new MinMax(min, max);
        return true;
    }
```

However this doesn't compile since apparently the out parameter needs to be written. What's the correct way to fix this? I would like to be able to use the function so that if the parsing fails, the parameter passed into it remains unchanged. I guess one way would be to add something like:

```
result = result;
```

but this line issues a warning.

Comment: If MinMax is `class` It's reference type, and if you don't like set value for it (i.e in your case) you shouldn't pass it as `out`, as Mitch Wheat, says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming MinMax is a reference type, just assign null to it. Just like any other TryParse method would work.

Check out this code:

```
    string s = "12dfsq3";
    int i = 444;
    int.TryParse(s, out i);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

i will be set to 0 instead of remaining at 444.

Comment: Ok, I initially wanted `result` to maintain it's value if the parsing failed, but if all other `TryParse` methods assigns `null` I guess it's better to follow this pattern and adapt the client of the code instead. Will accept in three minutes ;)

Answer (score 3):

Pass by ref:

```
public static bool TryParse(string s, ref MinMax result)
```

which means you will have to ensure the `result` parameter is initialised.

Update: It is better to stick to the well known semantics of `TryParse`. (I'm sometimes critised for answering the real question not the one that was asked! On this occasion it was the opposite!)

Comment: Surely not?  This changes the semantics of the call and suggests that the caller can supply a value for `result`.  In fact, the compiler will require that they do.  `ref` should be used very, very, very sparingly IMHO, and not here.

Comment: @batwad: the poster states "I would like to be able to use the function so that if the parsing fails, the parameter passed into it remains unchanged"

Answer (score 2):

Given that an out parameter doesn't even need to be initialized by the caller, you really have to do something with it.

You could use a ref parameter instead, those don't require you to touch them in your function.

Answer (score 1):

The only correct way to not update an out variable is to throw an exception. Change `out` to `ref`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like these answers telling you to use a `ref` parameter as it changes the semantics of the method and will require callers to pass an initialised value.

Set `result` to the default value for `MinMax`, which is `null` if it's a reference type, or use the `default` operator.

```
result = default(MinMax);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value of the `out` variable. You could use `ref` as other answers have suggested, but I wouldn't recommend it - that's not how the standard `TryParse` pattern is supposed to work. Besides, it's ugly and unnecessary.

It doesn't really matter what `result` contains in the failure case, since the `bool` that you return indicates whether the parsing was successful or not. Just return `new MinMax(0, 0)` or, if you prefer, `default(MinMax)`:

```
public static bool TryParse(string s, out MinMax result)
{
    string[] parts = s.Split(' ');
    if (parts.Length == 2)
    {
        float min, max;
        if (float.TryParse(parts[0].Trim(), out min)
                && float.TryParse(parts[1].Trim(), out max))
        {
            result = new MinMax(min, max);
            return true;
        }
    }

    result = default(MinMax);    // or just use "result = new MinMax(0, 0);"
    return false;
}
```